What does 'walk out' mean in 'You go out for a walk out in a green space which helps with fitness'?

You go out for a walk out in a green space which helps with fitness –
that also helps to improve your mental health, reduces loneliness,
improves sleep, and can also help to reduce one’s blood pressure.
These outcomes aren’t independent of each other.

'walk out' seems to not have the noun part of speech.
What is the kind of usage of 'a walk out'?

It's an unedited phrase. The second out is wrong.

Given the source appears to be Australian, perhaps the author was thinking of going out for a walkabout.

Perhaps it's a mis-heard 'work out'.

I'm not sure if the sentence is wrong, but it's certainly not the way I would say it. The word out is repeated; I would only say it once.
Either:

You go out for a walk in a green space...

Or:

You go for a walk out in a green space.

In both cases we are going for a walk, not a "walk out". Out in this context is a preposition describing where the walk will take place: outside.
The other possibility, which would make the sentence definitely wrong, is that the writer meant to say work out, which is a valid noun phrase and describes the kind of physical exercise routine that a person might do at their local gym.

I think more likely the author intended walkabout (perhaps which some dumb spell-checker didn't recognize, so changed it to the completely unconvincing work out).

+1 but I'm not sure either "out" is a preposition, as "for a walk" and "in a green space" are not noun phrases.

"Walk" and "out" aren't meant in combination. The second "out" is part of the phrase "out in a green space."
It's clunky and poorly written, but you're chasing a wild goose thinking the author meant "walk out" as a term.
